# rpm --ignoreos equivalent in yum

Tags: yum, rpm

I have created an rpm on OSX that I want to install on CentOS6. I can do that with the following command:

```
rpm -i --ignoreos <some_package>.rpm
```

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent command for yum, something like:

```
yum localinstall <some_package>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such built-in capability in `yum`. However, you can look into [this plugin](https://github.com/toomasp/yum-plugin-ignoreos) which should give you the functionality you want.